# how to display many data from datastore to website using GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt-rpc

I am trying to make a web app using GWT and its my first time using this tool. I am also using GAE datastore. I want to load data to my web application from my datastore using rpc calls.I am using a menu and when the user choose something then the right method is called through the rpc so it can load the right data.I am using an arraylist to save the data because i want to display many of them in my web page.I managed to load the arraylist but i don't like the way it looks on my webpage.What should i change? Is there any other way i can do that? The code is below:

**The class which loads the data**

```
List<String>places=new ArrayList<String>();

DatastoreService ds= DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

public List<String> display(String s){

    Query q=new Query(s);
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
    for (Entity place : pq.asIterable()) {
        String result = place.getProperties().toString();

        places.add(result);

    }return places;
```

**My async call**

```
public void onSuccess(Object result) {
        CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(new TextCell());
        final ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellList);
        final TextBox valueBox = new TextBox();

         List<String> list = dataProvider.getList();
         list.add(result.toString());

         VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
         vPanel.add(cellList);
         RootPanel.get().add(vPanel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `place.getProperties().toString()` will not look good unless you further manipulate the result string, which is complicated and unnecessary.

You need to create a Java class to represent your `Place` entity, and return an ArrayList of these Place objects instead of strings. Then you have control over which properties to display and how to display them.

Comment: so instead of this line in my code :
for (Entity place : pq.asIterable()) {
        String result = place.getProperties().toString();

        places.add(result);

    }return places;
i should just put the entity in my arraylist. Right?

Comment: You need to convert your Datastore entity into a an object of your own Place class.